# MAMP: PHP -m shows oci8 enabled, but not in phpinfo

Tags: php, oracle, mamp, oracle-call-interface

My objective is to connect to Oracle database through OCI8 which is available through:

```
pecl install oci8-2.0.11
```

To achieve that, I've been following various tutorials on the Net to make it work.

I followed the following tutorials:

1. http://www.baldwhiteguy.co.nz/technical/index_files/mac-osx-oracle-instantclient.html
2. http://www.enavigo.com/2012/01/04/enabling-oracle-oci8-php-extension-on-os-x-snow-leopard/
3. http://tomytree22.blogspot.my/2014/09/oci-driver-installation-on-mac.html

These tutorials are enough to run SQL Plus. I am also able to successfully run pecl install oci-8.20.11 and get this output:

```
You should add "extension=oci8.so" to php.ini
```

In the 3rd tutorial I listed above, I followed all except under *instantclient library has some hardcoded paths we need to take care of:*

When I run php -m, I can see the oci8 is there, but I don't see it inside my phpinfo. What did I do wrong?

When I tried to connect to the Oracle database anyway, I am stuck with this:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect()
```

I hope someone here can help me. I'm using El Capitan.

Comment: I guess this might be causing a clash.

how were you installing PHP?
What version of Oracle DB are you using and where is it located?

Comment: @FiidoFirdauz It might be causing a clash? What do you mean by that? I'm using Oracle Instant Client. I'm using MAMP for my development (PHP 5.6.10).

Comment: First checking your code running on php 64/32 bit . If  PHP is 32 bit, you'll need to use 32 bit Oracle libraries

Comment: @FiidoFirdauz My PHP is 64 bit. And yeah, I'm using 64-bit Oracle library as well.

Answer (score 2):

So I fixed it. Here's how I get to the solution.

I looked into my php log (make sure you enabled your PHP to log all errors! Just go to your error_log path to look for your error) and I found this:

> [06-May-2016 09:48:12 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/oci8.so' - dlopen(/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/oci8.so, 9): Library not loaded: /ade/b/3071542110/oracle/rdbms/lib/libclntsh.dylib.11.1

and

> [09-May-2016 04:53:51 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/oci8.so' - dlopen(/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/oci8.so, 9): Library not loaded: /ade/dosulliv_ldapmac/oracle/ldap/lib/libnnz11.dylib

So oci8.so is not loaded because there are two libraries that are not loaded.

**Here's how I fixed it:**

And that means, the one that I skipped which is *instantclient library has some hardcoded paths we need to take care of:* is the one I needed. So I run these commands (copy pasted from the tutorial):

```
sudo mkdir -p /ade/b/3071542110/oracle/rdbms/lib/
sudo ln -sf /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/lib/php/instantclient_11_2/libclntsh.dylib.11.1 /ade/b/3071542110/oracle/rdbms/lib/libclntsh.dylib.11.1
sudo mkdir -p /ade/dosulliv_ldapmac/oracle/ldap/lib/
sudo ln -sf /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/lib/php/instantclient_11_2/libnnz11.dylib /ade/dosulliv_ldapmac/oracle/ldap/lib/libnnz11.dylib
```

and then I restarted my MAMP. And now I got what I want, which is OCI8. Now the info is available on my PHPInfo.

[image: My PHPInfo OCI8]

Hope this will help the rest of guys who are embarking the same path of setting up OCI to connect to Oracle on MAMP.